# Is it practical to implement data structure shared for multiple processes?

Tags: c, data-structures, concurrent-programming

I googled quite a lot for shared(concurrent) data structures,

all of which seem to be shared for threads,not for processes.

Take a shared hash table for example,

if it were to be implemented as shared for multiple processes,

all `malloc` or equivalent calls for the table needs to be replaced by `shmget`,etc.

But I don't see such an example.

Is it practical to implement data structure shared for multiple processes at all?

Does the fact that I don't find such an example imply that it's impractical?

Comment: Is it really required for your application? I'm going to guess it isn't common as it isn't worth the complexity.

Comment: @rsaxvc ,I'm trying to find a way that makes full use of multi-core cpu, but so far seems no perfect solution.

Comment: It seems like you should be able to do that with just threads. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that the is no platform-independent way. So assuming that you are on some unix system, for sharing between arbitrary processes I'd probably use `mmap` on a file. The nice thing about that is that you can have arbitrarily many processes sharing it, easy way to identify the sharing point (a file) and you have an actual persistent storage for free as well (makes debugging easier). It doesn't matter how complex is your data structure - it's just a piece of memory. So the only issue that remains to be solved by you is how to synchronize write access between your processes - and that is really app-specific (not easy if you allow writes from multiple processes, though).

Some sample code:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
...
struct my_structure *buf; /* just an example - can be arbitrary complex */
...
int fd = open("foo.bin", O_RDWR);
if (fd == -1) { /* if the file doesn't exist create your initial structure */
  fd = open("foo.bin", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0700);
  /* ... allocate enough space in the file or pre-fill with the structure ... */
  /* (for safety you may do that in a separate process or using move-in atomically) */
}
buf = (struct my_structure*) mmap(0, sizeof(*buf), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE|MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
...
/* memory in buf is now shared across all processes ... */
/* if you want to synchronize that shared memory with the file use msync, but it's not needed for the sharing */
msync(buf, sizeof(*buf), MS_ASYNC);
/* when you're done, unmap */
munmap(buf, sizeof(*buf));
```

Comment: Thanks for the point:) So by using `mmap` you leave all caching work for OS,right? This may cause serious performance issue though..And we're back to the question, is it worth the effort at all? Is multiple processes no caching better than one process with caching?

Comment: You should not need to worry about caching because it is shared memory - the processes are not actually using the file to access it but the identical memory mapped by the first process. So the sharing itself should not be affected, the only effect you may see is depending on how eager is the OS of synchronizing the memory with the file without explicit `msync` and that is system-dependent. You could also use `mmap` without a file, but that limits how you can spawn the processes (if you use `fork()` then it's automatic).

Answer (score 0):

Don't implement shared structures as far as possible, period, because that opens up an entire field of problems that you can fall into.

If you do have to (and that too for processes), you will have to set out to do it yourself.

But, if you can use [IPC](http://faculty.cs.tamu.edu/bettati/Courses/313/2009C/Slides/POSIXIPC.pdf), that might be the easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely share memory (data-structure) with multiple processes and make the process communicate with each other to make them work in a synchronize manner when accessing the shared memory/data-structure.

Please go through various examples given [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html)

Comment: I know about IPC stuff, they involve no data structure as complex as hash table ,b-tree etc, and many of them are only for sharing between 2 processes, or multiple ones..

Comment: They are certainly possible - in C you will have to create your own malloc/free code to manage the placement of elements in a dynamic stucture as a b-tree etc. We lazily implement some as fixed size arrays.

Comment: I'm sure this is possible,but is there an example? As I said above, this will require one to replace many `malloc` with `shmget`,which may cause performance issue, and that may be the reason I don't find such an example yet -- there's no such an example at all.

Comment: Yes of course, all `malloc()` which was used to allocate memory for your shared data-structure should now be replaced with `shmget()`. But in order to share the memory with multiple process, you need to know the `key` (using which the shared memory was created. And, this key should be constant (i.e. all the process that wants to share the shared memory should use the same parameter to `ftok()` to get the key. [This](http://kohala.com/start/unpv22e/unpv22e.chap12.pdf) contains some examples. Hope this helps!

Comment: That's the real trouble,we'll gain no performance benifit doing it this way rather than a single process...

Comment: @new_perl If you find my answer help you find something useful, please feel free to upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use shmget, and you'll need to use memory barriers to enforce read/write scheduling to occur between them. This prevents the compiler and CPU from scheduling away soft locks and such. Barriers can be OS and/or arch specific, so if you post your OS, I may be able to help with that.

So to answer the questions, yes, no. But...

Concurrent data structures are pretty complicated, and if at all possible, I'd suggest trying to shrink the critical section down to something fast enough that it can be locked/unlocked with a portable mutex.